# Use column field inside Django filter method

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a field in the database which comes as a string (`x`). I need to convert it in a format to be used inside `filter()` method. How is this possible?

Also when field is none i want to use something to return True. Like `filter(1=1)` to get rid of the error

```
def DeviceDetailView(request,device_id):
    View_filtering = Applications.objects.values_list('view_filtering').filter(pk=2)
    #x gives data_type=1
    x= View_filtering[0][0]

    #should be DeviceData.objects.filter(data_type=1) but x is a string
    DeviceData.objects.filter(x)
```

Comment: `DeviceData` has a field named `x` or what do you mean exactly? I don't understand what you want, please be more specific, maybe show your models.

Comment: x comes from another model instance. `view_filtering = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=200)` Then i want to filter from DeviceData object. e.g. DeviceData.objects.filter(data_type=1)

Comment: Please see my updated question. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what the problem is, but if it is that `x` is a string (let's say `x = '1'` and you need it to be an integer, why don't you just cast it to int? `x = int(x)`

Comment: `x` comes from database as  varchar. So it can store strings, then use that inside the `filter()` e.g. `device_id=5`

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that `x` can be something like `x = 'device_id=5'`, right? The value of `x` is an expression that should be used inside the `filter` method?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Convert string to expression

Comment: Alright, let me elaborate an answer with a possible solution for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the value of `x` is an expression that should be used inside the filter method, i.e `x` can be something like `x = 'device_id=5'`, then you can do the following:

```
x = 'device_id=5'
temp_list = x.split('=')
```

Now that you have separated the keyword and the value from the expression, then you can use `temp_list` inside the filter method as follows, unpacking a dictionary created in-place:

```
DeviceData.objects.filter(**{temp_list[0]: temp_list[1]})
```

For the case `x` equals `None` or there's some other problem with the value of the keywords inside `x`, you can handle those exceptions as follows (following EAFP approach):

```
x = 'device_id=5'
try:
    temp_list = x.split('=')
    qs = DeviceData.objects.filter(**{temp_list[0]: temp_list[1]})
except (ValueError, TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
    qs = DeviceData.objects.all()
```

Comment: Okay, take in mind that x can return `None` so in that case,  x should return a default value

Comment: What should be that default value?

Comment: something like you do in select statement `where 1=1` to return true just to get rid of the error

Comment: You can use `try` statement and handle both `ValueError` and `TypeError` exceptions. Let me update the answer ;-)